# fire click event on a link from another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, window

so I was able to trigger a click event on a span from another window using:

```
var openerBody = $(window.opener.document.body);
$('.thespan', openerBody).click();
```

but then when I change that span object to an `<a>` tag, the click trigger stops working...

Is there a way to trigger a click event from another window on an `<a>` tag?

Comment: are you suggesting that this method is supposed to work on <a> tags?

Comment: I am, indeed. It's possible maybe you're missing something

Comment: Actually, no, I lied. Some browsers won't allow a Js click of a link for security purposes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers won't allow you to call `click` on an `a` tag, to prevent you form over-manipulating the user's browser. But you can use the `href` attribute to redirect the user.

```
window.location.href = $('.thespan', openerBody).attr('href');
```